# Performance considerations of inheritance in C#

Tags: c#, performance, inheritance

Does the compiler produce the same IL if I make a class with `public int I;` (or any other field) vs making a class that inherits from a base class that has `public int I;`?

Either way the resulting class behaves identically, but does the compiler behave identically?

I.e., is the compiler just copy-pasting code from base classes into the derived classes, or is it actually creating two different class objects when you inherit?

```
class A
{
    public int I;
}

class B : A
{
}
```

Now is there any performance difference between the following two DoSomething() calls?

```
var a = new A();
var b = new B();
DoSomething(a.I);
DoSomething(b.I); // Is this line slower than the above line due to inheritance?
```

Try to ignore any optimizations the compiler might do for this special case. My question is about whether inheritance in C# in general has an associated performance penalty. Most of the time I don't care, but sometimes I want to optimize a piece of high frequency code.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to do premature optimizations?

Comment: Looks like something you could easily benchmark yourself. Why didn't you?

Comment: jgauffin: read the last sentence in my question :)

Comment: Oded: A few reasons: benchmarking like this is error prone, someone watching SO questions right now probably knows the answer of the top of their head, sharing this info so that it's easily searchable is part of the point of SE sites, and I don't know yet how to look at C# IL.

Comment: +1 for interesting question. Similar but not the same question had been asked here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930418/abstract-vs-normal-class-inheritance-performance

Comment: Thanks Splendor, I guess I fail at searching -- that answer states that no, there is no performance difference.

Comment: Are you asking about the cost of *making the call* or the performance of the method itself?

Comment: Jon: The cost of making the call. Well, I'm really asking about the cost of accessing the field `I`, and whether there is an extra indirection of some kind to access the base class' field in the case where `I` is inherited.

Comment: Essentially I'm asking: Are there any performance pitfalls associated with inheritance?

Comment: Jon Skeet: I'm sorry, I meant to be calling the method on `a.I`, not on `a`, which I think was the reason my question may have been misunderstood. I've edited the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What the compiler emits is identical; indeed, even when calling a non-virtual instance method on a sealed class it uses `Callvirt` - which is the same as it would use calling any method with polymorphism.

And no: it isn't copy/paste - the code you wrote in `A` remains as part of `A`. And no, you don't get 2 objects just because of inheritance. It is combining the *behaviour*; an instance of `B` **also has** the implementation from `A` - but not via copy paste: a `B` ***is also*** an `A` - i.e. a `Dog` is also a `Mammal`, etc.

Comment: Wait, so to be clear: if I inherit a method from a base class, vs calling a method on a sealed class that does not inherit from any class, the performance of these method calls will also be the same?

Comment: @Olhovsky in most measurable ways, yes; there may be some subtleties with inlining, but nothing to get excited about. Oh, and re "that does not inherit from any class" - any class is inherited from `object` which is a class.